# encodeURIComponent() adds too many characters

Tags: javascript, php

Either my encodeURICOmponent() in java script is adding to many characters or I don't understand exactly how it works.

I am using this line of code:

```
    var encoded = encodeURIComponent(searchTerm);
```

When I look in the chrome inspect element after passing `Abt 12` it shows the encoded variable added to the URL as this:

```
Abt%252012
```

I would think it should be this:

```
Abt%12
```

So when I pass it through PHP I get really odd results when actually conducting the search.

Comment: Sorry... that is not how encoding works... for each character to be escaped it has a escape sequence.... you can't dictate it

Comment: So I need to decode it in php then?

Comment: Also the encoded value for `Abt 12` is `Abt%2012`

Comment: No, it should be `Abt%2012`. You're getting `Abt%252012` because you're passing the string through `encodeURIComponent()` twice.

Comment: since it is url encoded, in server side you should get the correct value... there is no need to decode it

Comment: The space is encoded as `%20`, but if you pass the encoded value again through the `encode` method then the `%` is encoded again as `%25` that is why you are getting `%2520`... so fixing that should solve your problem

Comment: So I just searched through my entire code. I am not encoding it twice. I encode it then I store it in html5 with           window.localStorage.setItem("search", searchTerm); 

The question is does window.localStorage.setItem encode it the second time?

Comment: @Mike no it doesn't... can you alert the value of `searchTerm` before call to encode and value of `encoded` variable after it

Comment: Will do that right now, hang on a second

Comment: So after it says Abt%2012. Maybe I am encoding it again in PHP.....checking that now. But its adding to the URL with the other so I would think not...

Comment: Does ajax auto encode, if I use this: $.get("http://website.php", {
                p: encoded,
            })

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89339/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-mike).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form the comments, it looks like you are sending the value to server via jQuery ajax request, then it will take care of parameter encoding, so there is no need for you to encode it again.

```
$.get("website.php", { p: searchTerm, })
```

Comment: Check out the discussion more, this still does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Mike maybe you're solving a wrong problem? Share your php-related code to let us see what you're doing wrong

Comment: Your right its in the php code. When I am parsing my json I get this error,  cannot read property '0' of undefined. How can I have the code do like an else if its undefined?

Comment: Sorry, whether the error is in PHP or in javascript.. you also need to share the code that is causing the error